# Firebase Login Error: Error logging in with Google

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a login screen in which you can login through Google, but when I click to login and then select the account, it stays in the same activity. The error in the Log is the following:

```
W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
E/GoogleProvider: Error logging in with Google. 16 null
EGLNativeWindowType 0x704a430010 disconnect failed
Activity resumed, time: 182884358
```

The code of the activity is the following:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.firebase.ui.auth.AuthUI;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 123;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        startActivityForResult(AuthUI.getInstance().createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setAvailableProviders(
                                Arrays.asList(  new AuthUI.IdpConfig.GoogleBuilder().build(),
                                        new AuthUI.IdpConfig.FacebookBuilder().build()))
                        .setIsSmartLockEnabled(false)
                        .setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(firebaseAuth -> {
            if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!= null) {
                startHomeActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if(currentUser != null) {
            startHomeActivity();
        }
    }

    private void startHomeActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

I already signed Firebase with SHA1 and activated the login options in the service.

Comment: Please share the enitre code for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps to solve are: 

1 - keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore

2 - copy SHA1 (it has to be SHA1 because that's what they use for Oauth)

3 - log into your firebase console -> project settings -> general -> android app

4 - scroll down and add your SHA1 fingerprint to list of fingerprints

5 - download new google-services.json and replace in your android studio project .

6 - delete app from phone and re-deploy

Answer (score 1):

Try to add your SHA1 for your package name in the settings of your project in [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com).

Comment: That was the problem!